# Deploying Project Server 2013

Tags: 2013, installation, project-server

Assume that I have a current SharePoint 2013 environment, with the latest cumulative updates applied (using the Foundation + SP2013 package). Now I want to deploy Project Serve 2013 to it.

What should be the installation order here, and how would I get the latest Project updates applied as well? Do I install Project Server 2013, the March update package for PS2013, and then the latest combined cumulative update package? Or would I install all the update packages first, then Project Server 2013 itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the March PU in the updates folder of the Project Server media, then post-installation install the updates to bring the PS bits up to date with the farm.